# Enable diagnostic settings for Storage account using ARMTemplate

Tags: azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-diagnostics

Storage account deployed from ARMTemplate is creating diagnostic settings as disabled.

How to enable diagnostics status using ARMTemplate or Powershell script?

Want to automate the process to deploy diagnostic settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using ARM templates in the newer Bicep format. In the example, it configures diagnostics settings for:

- StorageAccount

  - Blob
  - File
  - Queue
  - Table

To reduce the template length, it configures only the `StorageRead` on the storage account services.

```
param name string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param sku string

@description('Resource ID for the destination log analytics workspace.')
param logAnalyticsWorkspaceId string

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  properties: {
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
    }
  }
}

resource diagnosticsStorage 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: storageAccount
  name: 'diagnostics00'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
    metrics: [
      {
        category: 'Transaction'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-06-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

resource diagnosticsBlob 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: blobService
  name: 'diagnostics00'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'StorageRead'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource fileService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices@2021-06-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

resource diagnosticsFile 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: fileService
  name: 'diagnostics00'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'StorageRead'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource queueService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices@2021-06-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

resource diagnosticsQueue 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: queueService
  name: 'diagnostics00'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'StorageRead'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource tableService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices@2021-06-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

resource diagnosticsTable 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: tableService
  name: 'diagnostics00'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'StorageRead'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below URL to enable the Diagnostics Settings for Azure Storage Account using ARM Template:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings#diagnostic-setting-for-azure-storage

Comment: I am getting errors for the template in microsoft link. I just want resource section for blob,queue,table,fileshare. Right now dont have much time to troubleshoot. Is there any simple way to write separate small code script for each one using ARM/powershell

Comment: I tried with powershell command let as Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "/subscriptions/630f62f40f1/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sttest" -Enabled $True....This is failing with forbidden access issue.

Comment: I tried with ARMTemplate as suggested in Microsoft site. I get error as: InvalidTemplate: Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/2de18693e/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/nested' at line '1' and column '1024'. 'The template parameter 'logWorkspaceResourceId' is not found.

Comment: Can you update the question with the ARM Template? Looks like you are using logWorkspaceResourceId in the resources section but not declared it in parameters section.